# How to set UISlider' trackImage (using pattern)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uislider

I hope to how to set UISlider's trackImage.

My image is this. 
[image]

I want to use pattern.
But, I cannot find way.

[image]

Please tell me  hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a resizable image and make it so that the resizing is done using tiling. As you don't have any caps on the image you can do something like this...

```
UIImage *trackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TheImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

Then use this image on the slider...

```
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:trackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This will then tile the image horizontally. As long as your pattern matches up edge to edge then it will work.

Comment: you should probably mention it's only available 6.0+

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a `UIColor` using the image as a pattern, and then setting it in the slider.

```
[slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:/*your image*/]];
```